# Escaping from chroot()

Tags: c, unix, chroot

I'm working on a webserver in UNIX environment with C language. Currently, I have done jailing the process but now I cannot use syslog and logging to a file option and that's basically due to the changed root path.

New root path for the program is it's directory. I could not escape from it to real root "/" in order to use these functions and go back to jail root path again.

Are there any other alternatives or solutions to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of using `chroot()` is to make the real root inaccessible, so easy formula: If you can break it, you don't need it.

So, you should make syslog accessible from within your chroot environment instead. How? Just `openlog()` prior to `chroot()`. After that, you can `syslog()` even though you wouldn't be able to `openlog()` it anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I could not think of that! It is fixed now.

Comment: Sometimes, one is blind to the easiest solutions ;)

Comment: Hi, I have another problem, I guess they are related and someone already opened a thread for it but no luck. When chrooting the localtime zone changes. I read something about linking the /etc/ time folders to chroot path etc. But not sure.

Comment: copying and pasting /etc/localtime into /chrootspath/etc/ seems to fixing the problem. But will this fix work on other computers too? Like I do not want to copy, paste localtime on each computer.

Comment: you can hardlink that file. The point is: Localtime works by reading /etc/localtime and following the instruction there. If that file is not present in the chroot path, then there just is no configuration for local time.

Comment: I used cp command with execl (with forking/waiting) and its working now. I tried symlink() first but no luck.

Comment: symlinks are not allowed to break jail, otherwise, jailbreaking would be trivial. I said HARD link. But copying works too.

Answer (score 0):

If your root is the working directory, don't use chroot, and remove the '/' at the beggining of all the relative path you use, or add '.' before this '/'.
Use chroot only if you want to fully work as if it was your system root.

Answer (score 0):

If both env are on the same file system, you can use hard links so that under the chroot'ed env you see files "outside". It may not be so easy to configure everything to work, but it is possible. Change your viewpoint: don't try to escape from chroot, try to include things into.